# Spring rest docs failing to document pathParameters using WebTestClient

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-restdocs

After upgrading to Spring-test-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT, spring rest docs is failing to document path parameters complaining it can't find `urlTemplate`.

```
webTestClient.mutateWith(csrf()).get()
        .uri("/products/{productId}", productId)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk()
        .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .expectBody()
        .consumeWith(document("find-product-by-id",
                pathParameters(
                        parameterWithName("productId").description("...")
                ),
                responseFields(getProductResponseFields())));
```

Error log:

```
urlTemplate not found. If you are using MockMvc did you use RestDocumentationRequestBuilders to build the request?
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: urlTemplate not found. If you are using MockMvc did you use RestDocumentationRequestBuilders to build the request?
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.request.PathParametersSnippet.extractUrlTemplate(PathParametersSnippet.java:126)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.request.PathParametersSnippet.extractActualParameters(PathParametersSnippet.java:113)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.request.AbstractParametersSnippet.verifyParameterDescriptors(AbstractParametersSnippet.java:89)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.request.AbstractParametersSnippet.createModel(AbstractParametersSnippet.java:74)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.request.PathParametersSnippet.createModel(PathParametersSnippet.java:98)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet.document(TemplatedSnippet.java:78)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.generate.RestDocumentationGenerator.handle(RestDocumentationGenerator.java:191)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.webtestclient.WebTestClientRestDocumentation.lambda$document$0(WebTestClientRestDocumentation.java:77)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultBodyContentSpec.lambda$consumeWith$3(DefaultWebTestClient.java:665)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.ExchangeResult.assertWithDiagnostics(ExchangeResult.java:223)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultBodyContentSpec.consumeWith(DefaultWebTestClient.java:665)
```

Looks like DefaultWebTestClient is setting the uriTemplate to null when constructing uri but can't find a way to override it.

Comment: You should create a bug report.

Comment: Are you sure that `DefaultWebTestClient` is setting `uriTemplate` to `null`? Looking at [the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d3087537d59556cb150d29fe055008f2cb8e10be/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/DefaultWebTestClient.java#L196-L219) it will only do that when called with a `URI` or `Function<UriBuilder, URI>` and your code above is not doing that. It's calling `uri(String uriTemplate, Object... uriVariables)` which will set the template.

Comment: All the uri methods eventually calls the `RequestBodySpec uri(URI uri)` method which sets the uriTemplate to null, so does not matter which method I used. @AndyWilkinson

Comment: You're right. Sorry, I missed that you were using 5.3 snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's a regression in the latest Spring Framework 5.3 snapshots and I don't believe you can work around it. I've raised a [Spring Framework issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25854). In the meantime, you could use Spring Framework 5.3.0.RC1 as it was released before the problem was introduced.